# Multiple Apache instances

Tags: apache-2.2, template

here is some background information, I'm writing a Apache/Tomcat cluster installer basically it is a script that can be called with a domain name and a base port e.g. www.example.com 10010 this scipt generates 2 tomcat and 2 apache instances with a lb in front and all the backend connections are automaticly configured, the apache--- >tomcat connection is made trough mod_proxy_ajp and a balancer.

The Problem is apache, I have compiled apache from source  so that it can be used as a template for all other instances, the bad thing is the --prefix so that the executables refer to the "template" config files.

Is there a way to compile apache as a "template" with a relative path or someting like that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need to fiddle with prefix? If you need two (or more) apaches with different configurations, you can just point apache to different config files and server roots using command-line options:

```
-d directory       : specify an alternate initial ServerRoot
-f file            : specify an alternate ServerConfigFile
```

Comment: Ahh of course sorry for that question and thank for pointing me to the right direction.